# How do I display my searchable data from console to a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, api, swiftui, decode, combine

I have the following structs:

```swift
struct Search: Codable {
    struct Data: Codable {
        struct Item: Codable {
            let symbol: String
            let description: String
        }

        let items: [Item]
    }
   
    let data: Data
}
```

Search function:

```swift
func getSearchkData(for search: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.tastyworks.com/symbols/search/\(search)")!
    URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap { element -> JSONDecoder.Input in
            guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            return element.data
        }
        .decode(type: Search.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .sink { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                return
            case .finished:
                return
            }
        } receiveValue: { [unowned self] searchAPI in                
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.searchAPI.append(searchAPI)
            }
            print(searchAPI)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

Im able to get the search working in the console but how can I display that exact info into my list?
[results of search when I type 'A' into the searchable in swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hchgw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @88Camino and welcome to SO! Your example difficile to recreate read this article to race you chance get an right answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Seem the problem is your `reSearchData` there is no adding receiving values to the array that will be use for the list. You can do it directly in here

```
receiveValue: { [unowned self] searchAPI in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.searchAPI.append(searchAPI) // need to change array here
            }
```

Or if you use this `searchAPI` array need to `.map` elements in right format for feed for the list